# How to change the layout and/or css of the default XAMPP file browser?

Tags: xampp

So you know when you browse to a XAMPP installation in your browser, but XAMPP can't find a `index.php` or equivalent file, it just shows a file browser thing? (Pictured below.)

Well the name column doesn't scale with the length of the file names, and I often find myself needing guess which folder I was looking for. Is there a way to change the layout and or CSS of this default file browser?

[image: XAMPP default file browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found its solution on this [link](https://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/)

[image]

I am attaching the image too if the link gets removed.